# How do I see a list of all currently defined environment variables in a Linux bash terminal?

Tags: environment-variables

In a Linux bash terminal, there are often many environment variables that have been set, like `$PATH` and `$HOME`.

Is it possible to see all of the environment variables that have been set? How?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/275965/how-to-list-all-variables-names-and-their-current-values

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**TL;DR:** use `(set -o posix ; set)`

---

According to the Bash manual you can [use the `set` built-in command to show all of the environment variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html#The-Set-Builtin) that have been set. The `set` command will also display the definitions of any functions. If you only want to see the variables, and not the functions, then you can turn on POSIX mode before running the set command. The easiest way to do that is with `set -o posix`, but that will leave POSIX mode on until you turn it off with `set +o posix`.

Therefore, the following command will show all of the defined environment variables by using a subshell without affecting POSIX compliance in your current shell.

```
(set -o posix ; set)
```

@RedGrittyBrick and @iglvzx suggested using the `env` command, however this command will not provide a complete listing of environment variables. `env` will only show the varaibles that have been marked for export. Compare the output of `env | sort` and `export -p` and you will see what I mean. You can run `comm -23 <(set -o posix; set) <(env|sort)` if you want to see which environment variables are not being exported.

The reason for the discrepancy is that `env` is a separate executable as opposed to `set` which is a shell built-in command. According to the Bash manual, [when a command is executed that is not a shell built-in command or function it will only receive environment variables that have been marked for export in Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Execution-Environment.html#Command-Execution-Environment). There are many variables that are not exported. Therefore, if you wish to see all of the variables that your shell has defined, you must use the `set` command as stated in the manual.

You can easily test this behavior for yourself using the following commands.

```
MY_TEST_VARIABLE="This is my test variable."
set | grep MY_TEST_VARIABLE
env | grep MY_TEST_VARIABLE
```

You will see that `set` provides output while `env` does not.

Comment: > (set -o posix ; set)
I did not know that non-exported variables go to a subshell. Aaah...: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51903718/when-are-bash-variables-exported-to-subshells-and-or-accessible-by-scripts

Comment: I get `set: no such option: posix`.

Comment: @hugoderhungrige what version of bash are you using? `bash --version`

Comment: @Starfish 5.1.16(1)-release

Answer (score 27):

The `env` command with no arguments will print a list of the "exported" environment variables and their values. These variables are made visible to subprocesses - many other environment variables are not shown with this, and used inside the running shell only, eg for configuration.

Comment: I prefer `printenv`, since both `env` and `set` have other functions than just outputting the environment.

Comment: `env` will only print a list of environment variables that have been marked for export. It will not print all variables.

Comment: @Starfish is right - that means this accepted answer was very wrong. Edited to say it's listing exported variables only.

Comment: Why isn't this the top answer. It's so much simpler and more memorable.

Answer (score 18):

```
compgen -v
```

prints shell variables (but not the values).

```
compgen -e
```

prints exported variables i.e. those that get inherited by processes this shell starts (but not their values).

Difference between shell and exported variables: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3507/difference-between-environment-variables-and-exported-environment-variables-in-b?rq=1

Answer (score 11):

I arrived here from a search for how to order the output of `env` ***alphabetically***; it's quite simple

```
env | sort -f
```

- the `-f` option makes sort ignore case, which is what you probably want 99% of the time

Answer (score 3):

Combining some of the previous answers, I find the following useful:

```
compgen -v  | sort | while read var; do [ -z "${!var}" ] || echo $var=${!var} ; done
```

- `compgen -v` : Print all variables names, either local or exported.
- `sort` : Alphabetical order.
- `${!var}` : Get the value of $var (variable indirection).
- `-z` condition : Check if value is null, else print "variable=value".

Note:
`printenv` is great also, but it will only show a list of environment variables that have been exported, not local/bash variables.